# 3 facets can not be loaded android studio bug?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just opened my Android studio today and all my projects are broken I did not update anything, I keep getting this error if I keep them all nothing happens if I ignore nothing happen. so far the project can not load, how can I fix this.

r[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to Settings | Plugins and make sure that the Gradle and Android plugins are enabled.